# Attempting switching over to using inherentence with templates, but formatting keeps getting screwed up

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I am attempting to switch over someone else's Flask templates over to an inherited model to get rid of repetitive code/clean things up. However, the formatting keeps getting fudged. For example, the navbar should look something like the following (the blackish top bar):

[image]

However, it looks like the following after I use inheritance:

[image]

Note that this is a different page, so it is OK that the page content isn't the same as in the above image.

How I switched over was I merged all the links and scripts into my `base.html` file and started to take out repetitive code into separate files.

---

**`base.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Very Open Student Ware{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-ui.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='editor.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='general_course.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename="/Content/MIT.ico") }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pixlr.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header>{% block navbar %}{% endblock %}</header>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

---

**`navbar.html`**

```
<div id="Menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename="Content/MIT.png") }}" height="20px"/></a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="/IoT/1/1/1">IoT Course</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="/IoT/edit">Course editor</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="/save_to_dbx">Save Course to Dropbox</a></li>
        <li class="login"><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

**`login.html`**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block navbar %}{% include "navbar.html" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="text">
<h1>Log In</h1>
</div>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" value = "{{ request.form.username }}">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value = "{{ request.form.password }}">
    <input type="submit" class="LoginSubmit" value="Log in">
</form>
{% if error %}
    <p> <strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}</p>
{% endif %}

{% for messages in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <p>{{ messages }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

---

**Relevant piece of CSS**

```
#Menu {
    z-index: 1;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}

#Menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#Menu li {
    float: left;
    padding:10px;
    height: 20px;;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#Menu li.item {
        width: 15%;
}
#Menu li.item:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#Menu li.icon {
    width: 25%;
}

#Menu li.logout {
    float: right;
}

#Menu li.logout:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#Menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any thoughts on how to fix the weird formatting and what might be causing it? My hunch is that I put all the links and scripts into the same header section. Though it is odd that the `#Menu` id has the same styling across all files I have seen, so it doesn't seem like that would affect it.

**EDIT: ADDING WHOLE CSS FILES**

**`general_course.css`**

```
* { 
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
 *:focus {
     outline: none;
 }

#text {
    margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

#text a{
    color: whitesmoke;
}
body {
    background-image: url(/static/Background.png);
    background-size: 100%;
}
#Menu {
    z-index: 1;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}

#Menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#Menu li {
    float: left;
    padding:10px;
    height: 20px;;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#Menu li.item {
        width: 15%;
}
#Menu li.item:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#Menu li.icon {
    width: 25%;
}

#Menu li.logout {
    float: right;
}

#Menu li.logout:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#Menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-show {
    color: darkred;
}

#location {
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
#workspace {
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: darkred;
    float: left;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkred;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav h3:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: darkred;
}

#work {
    border-color: darkred;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-width: 1px;
    float: right;
}

#video {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#add-video {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#slides {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;

}

#nav h3 {
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    font-size: 120%;
    color: aliceblue;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav h4 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;


}
#nav h4 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkgray;
}

#nav h4 a:hover {
    color: #8C8C8C;
}

h5 {
    font-weight: 100;
}

#video_nav {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

#video-buttons {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;

}

#video-buttons2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;

}

.video-buttons {
    background-color:darkred;
    border:white;
    color: whitesmoke;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50px;
}

.video-buttons:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.video-buttons-select {
    background-color:white;
    border:darkred;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: darkred;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
}
.bold {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: darkred;
}

.show {
    background-color:darkred;
    border:white;
    color: whitesmoke;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#close {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    z-index: 10;
}
.close {
    background-color:darkred;
    border:white;
    color: whitesmoke;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.show:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}

.hide {
    background-color:white;
    border:darkred;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: darkred;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hide:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}

#layout-selector {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

#layout-selector ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#layout-selector li {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;

}

.mySlides {
    width: 100%;

}

.LoginSubmit {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: darkred;
}

.slide-button {
    font-size: 200%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-color: darkred;
    color: darkred;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slide-button:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#slide-buttons {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}


/* Editor stuff */

.editor-button {
    background-color:white;
    border:darkred;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 30%;
    color: darkred;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}

.editor-button:hover{
    font-weight: 500;
    border-width: 2px;
}

.editor-button a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkred;
}



#editor
{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#section
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: darkred;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    display: none;
}

canvas
{
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: darkred;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 15px;

    /*background:url(example.png);*/
}

.img {
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
    z-index: 30;

}

#flashcard {
    align-content: center;
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
    display: block;
}
button
{
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#drawingTools
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#toolType
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
}

#toolType button
{
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: darkred;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: darkred;

}

#toolType button:hover {opacity: 0.5;}

#colors
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}

#colors button
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#colors button:hover {opacity: 0.5;}

#black { background:black;}
#white { background:white;}
#red { background:indianred;}
#blue { background:dodgerblue;}
#green { background:mediumseagreen;}

#otherTools
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 100;
}

#otherTools button
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: #303030;
    color: white;
    font: 25px impact;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#otherTools button:hover { opacity: 0.5;}

#textinput {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

::-moz-selection{
    background-color:Transparent;
    color:#000;
    }

    ::selection {
    background-color:Transparent;
    color:#000;
    }
```

---

**`editor.css`**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
 *:focus {
     outline: none;
 }

body {
    background-color: white;
}
#Menu {
    z-index: 1;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}

#Menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#Menu li {
    float: left;
    padding:10px;
    height: 20px;;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#Menu li.item {
        width: 15%;
}
#Menu li.item:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#Menu li.icon {
    width: 25%;
}

#Menu li.logout {
    float: right;
}

#Menu li.logout:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#Menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#Workspace {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

button
{
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
 #chapters {
     width: 40%;
     margin: auto;
 }

.chapter {
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: white;
    background-color: darkred;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.chapter:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.link {
    color: white;
    background-color: darkred;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
    cursor: pointer;

}


ul {
    list-style: none;
}


.delete {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: darkred;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: darkred;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#delete:hover {
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
}
#video-index {
    display: flex;
}

#video {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;

}
#vid-links {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

#video-display {
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

#Workspace {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: darkred;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
}

#slides-index {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.mySlides {
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
    flex: 1;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 95%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #c9c9c9;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #969696;

}

input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
    border-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't 'fix a navbar', you should fix other content on the page.
Could you add styles for div#text and enclosed content?

Comment: @shiberz why not if you want the navbar to stay still while you scroll your page?

Comment: Because any element that follows after your navbar in DOM could overlap it if have proper style - there is no magic command to say 'stay on top anyway'

Comment: @shiberz I added the style sheets as a whole. Please see them below my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out the following links to stylesheets and it worked fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='editor.css') }}">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
```